# Json.loads error on reading mutiple json files from s3 bucket

Tags: python, json, amazon-s3

when I am passing manually json file as key to load in python shell then its working fine. code below

```
import os
import json
import boto3
import io
import requests
import botocore
bucket_name = 'dev-data'
folder_name = 'raw/test/'
key_source  = 'raw/test/extract_api_20200719.json'
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
json_obj = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=key_source)
json_data = json_obj["Body"].read().decode('utf-8')
print("############################json_data####################### :", json_data )
print("############################json_data_type################## :", type(json_data))
json_dict = json.loads(json_data)
print("############################json_dict####################### :", json_dict )
print("############################json_dict_type ################# :", type(json_dict))
```

However when using for loop to read JSON object from s3 bucket, then I am getting the error

```
import os
import json
import boto3
import io
import requests
import botocore
bucket_name = 'dev-data'
folder_name = 'raw/test/'
s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3_resource.Bucket(bucket_name)
for obj in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=folder_name):
    print('Object to extract :', obj)
    print('obj key: ', obj.key)
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    json_obj = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=obj.key)
    json_data = json_obj["Body"].read().decode('utf-8')
    json_dict = json.loads(json_data)
error:
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: What does the `obj key:` message show? Are you sure it's the same file you passed manually?

Comment: Yes, Barmar, it is the same file key, the second code is working if the last line is not there:json_dict = json.loads(json_data), when the last code line is there then obj.key also not coming.

Comment: what does `print(json_data)` show when the error happens?

Comment: Does `obj.key` include the prefix `raw/test/`?

Comment: json_data data is blank
json_data : 
Object to extract : s3.ObjectSummary(bucket_name='dev-data', key='raw/test/') 
obj key: raw/test/ , obj key does not have the json file name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the entries in `bucket.objects` don't have any JSON in the data, so check for that and skip them.

```
for obj in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=folder_name):
    print('Object to extract :', obj)
    print('obj key: ', obj.key)
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    json_obj = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=obj.key)
    json_data = json_obj["Body"].read().decode('utf-8')
    if not json_data:
        print("Skipping empty", obj.key)
        continue
    json_dict = json.loads(json_data)
```

Comment: Hi Barmar, I have tried this and it worked, Thanks a lot!